# index Cosmos Graph DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

How do I import graph data (json) into Azure Search?  I would like to search graph data AND document data in one.  I read that it doesn't support CosmosDB Graph API yet.  But I need to be able to do it in order to test moving my company from Neo4j to CosmosDB.

Thanks,
Donnie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-cosmosdb) article. If you need a tighter integration between Cosmos DB Graph API and Azure Search, vote for this [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/13285011-add-graph-databases-to-your-data-sources-eg-neo4) suggestion.

Comment: I did vote.  And I've read all these documents.  Guess I'm looking for a workaround.  From what I've read, it sounds like you can "push" it into Azure Search, instead of using the portal tools to "pull."  Yes, the portal tools don't support Cosmos Graph, but is it supported if you push using REST API https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/AddUpdate-or-Delete-Documents  .  I'm looking for an example of how to do this with Cosmos DB Graph data.  If not push, it might work "pull" it from storage by exporting JSON out of the Graph DB and uploading it to blob storage. Best way?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that you can put a graph DB connection string into Azure Search import and the indexing does work.  I still would like to see UserVoice implemented though!  This is good enough for us right now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can run a SQL query on your data in Cosmos DB to get the data in a JSON format. You can test this out by pulling up your Azure Cosmos DB account in the Azure Portal and executing a new SQL query in Data Explorer. If you don't need to use a skillset for Cognitive Search you can then [push the data to the index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents). There are some examples on that page. You will likely notice that your JSON includes complex types. You can follow the information here on how to handle [complex data types in Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-complex-data-types) right now. You can see the status of supporting complex types in indexes on this [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/6670910-modelling-complex-types-in-indexes).

Although you can add a Cosmos DB Graph document endpoint as part of the connection string in the Azure Search import data flow, we don't officially support that right now. It is under review as part of this [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/13285011-add-graph-databases-to-your-data-sources-eg-neo4).

If you don't want to manage pushing your data to the index and you want to use a data source that's officially supported by an indexer you could move your data to Azure Blob storage.